# How to use regex in python for a string

Tags: python

I have a string as

stringvalue="UPI-917020028084740-GOOG-PAYMENT@OKAXIS-805214272567-UPI"

I want to remove all special characters and number from the string except words by using regex in python

I want the output to be as

UPI GOOG PAYMENT OKAXIS UPI

Comment: Where do the spaces come from?

Comment: You should do at least some basic research befor asking here, see [ask]. Python regex handling is documented and finding examples is easy.

Comment: `' '.join(re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', s))`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the module `re`. The full documentation is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html for python 3 (just replace the '3' with a '2' for python 2)

Comment: I want to search a particular word like payment in the stringvalue